# How to get tag id from a record in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If we use `form_for` for a record, all input tags inside the form tag will automatically contain an attribute `id` with value like `id="post_3_title"`, `id="post_3_content"`.

In my case, I want to get those names to create javascript codes dynamically. I wonder if there is any way to do this. Any ideas?

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: you can give custom id to the field and can use it for your javascript code

Comment: @DevR Thanks, your solution works and that's the way I'm using in simple form, but in nested form, I think it can be a little lousy.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source code in `actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1218`.

```
    def tag_name_with_index(index)
      "#{@object_name}[#{index}][#{sanitized_method_name}]"
    end

    def tag_id
      "#{sanitized_object_name}_#{sanitized_method_name}"
    end

    def tag_id_with_index(index)
      "#{sanitized_object_name}_#{index}_#{sanitized_method_name}"
    end

    def sanitized_object_name
      @sanitized_object_name ||= @object_name.gsub(/\]\[|[^-a-zA-Z0-9:.]/, "_").sub(/_$/, "")
    end

    def sanitized_method_name
      @sanitized_method_name ||= @method_name.sub(/\?$/,"")
    end
```

It seems that we can make good use of them, however, they are all private methods. I think another solution is to implement some helper methods like this.